# Access 2010 Custom Ribbon is not working

Tags: vba, ms-access, customization, ribbon

I am running a FE BE setup and want to provide a custom Ribbon to all users of the FE.  I have tried to create a custom ribbon by creating the USysRibbons table.  I am successful at least in this to the extent that when I go into the options for the current database I can select the new ribbons as the default ribbon.  However when I close and reopen the DB the ribbon has not changed.  Fearing I got the xml all wrong I downloaded the sample ribbons 2 DB found here: http://www.accessribbon.de/en/?Downloads

I then tried to set one of those custom ribbons as the default for that DB and it did not work.  Similarly I have tried to set one of the custom ribbons to the Ribbon Name property of a form and launching that form does not change the ribbon. I have set the add-in user interface errors to show and do not get errors when the database loads. I suspect the issue is with the security posture of our computers (just a guess).  If that is a case changing the security settings will be a non starter with my IT group.

At the end of the day I need a pared down menu that includes the ability to export reports for the FE of my DB.  I can achieve this by customizing the ribbon and using macros for the buttons, but of course this only works for my computer.  I need a way to push this ribbon to all users.  So I either need the USysRibbons method to work or I need a way to programmatically import my customization file when the FE loads (or when the first form of my FE loads).

Any thoughts on pitfalls that might be preventing the USysRibbons from displaying, or on a way to automate the ribbon file import?

Comment: I've given up on this one and implemented the desired functionality via a custom right click menu.    If anyone has an idea I'd still welcome it.

Comment: Show xml and code (if not using USysRibbons). Macros have to be enabled (trusted location). You tried [SampleRibbon3](http://www.accessribbon.de/en/?Downloads:3). Provide a sample db.